# Best algo to retrieve elements from random id

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm currently trying to find the best data structure / algorithm that fits to my case:

I receive single unique random ids (uint32_t), and I create an element associated to each new id.

1. I need to retrieve elements from the id.
2. I also need to access the next and the previous element from any element (or even id) in the order of creation. The order of creation mainly depends on the *current* element, which is always accessible aside, so the new element should be its next.

Here is an example:

```
(12) <-> (5) <-> (8) <-> (1)
 ^                        ^
 '------------------------'
```

If I suppose the current element to be (8) and a new element (3) is created, it should look like:

```
(12) <-> (5) <-> (8) <-> (3) <-> (1)
 ^                                ^
 '--------------------------------'
```

An important thing to consider is that insertion, deletion and search happen with almost the same (high) frequency. Not completely sure about how many elements will live at the same time, but I would say max ~1000.

Knowing all of this, I think about using an AVL with ids as the sorted keys, keeping the previous and the next element too.

In C language, something like this:

```
struct element {
  uint32_t id;
  /* some other fields */
  struct element *prev;
  struct element *next;      
}

struct node {
   struct element *elt;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
};

static struct element* current;
```

Another idea may be to use a hash map, but then I would need to find the right hash function. Not completely sure it always beats the AVL in practice for this amount of elements though. It depends on the hash function anyway.

Is the AVL a good idea or should I consider something else for this case?

Thanks !

PS: I'm not a student trying to make you do my homework, I'm just trying to develop a simple window manager (just for fun).

Comment: IDs can be unique, or random, but not both.... as soon as a unique ID is used, the probability of it being used again becomes 0, while unused IDs have a probability of 1/N. Therefore, it is not random.

Comment: @abelenky It can still random, just not uniformly i.i.d random..

Comment: @abelenky Well, you may be right. I just mean these unique ids don't obey to any order (and if they do, I'm not supposed to consider it).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for some variation of what's called in java a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

This is basically a **combination of a [hash-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and a (bi-directional) [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)**.

The linked-list has elements in the desired order. Inserting an element in a known location (assuming you have the pointer to the correct location) is done in `O(1)`. Same goes for deletion. The linked list contains all the elements in their desired order.

The second data-structure is the hash-map (or tree map). This data structure maps from a key (your unique id), to a POINTER in the linked list. This way, given an id - you can quickly finds its location on the linked-list, and from there you can easily access next and previous elements.

high level pseudo code for insertion:

```
insert(x, v, y): //insert key=x value=v, after element with key=y
   if x is in hash-table:
        abort
   p = find(hash-table,y) //p is a pointer
   insert_to_list_after(x,v,p) //insert key=x,value=v right after p
   add(hash-table,x,p) //add x to the hash-table, and make it point to p.
```

high level pseudo code for search:

```
search(x):
    if x is not in hash-table:
        abort
    p = find(hash-table,x)
    return p->value;
```

deletion should be very similar to insertion (and in same time complexity).

Note that it is also fairly easy to find element that is after `x`:

```
p = find(hash-table,x)
if (p != NULL && p->next != NULL):
    return p->next->value
```

Comment: That was my first idea using two data structures: One to search by id, the other one (the double linked list) to find the next and prev element. Thanks, I'll take a look. I just need to find a good and fast hash function.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use a combination of two data structures - a list to store the elements in the order they are inserted and a hash map or binary search tree to implement an associative array(map) between the id and list node. You will perform the search using the associative array and will be able to access neighboring elements using the list. Deletion is also relatively easy, but you need to delete from both structures.

Complexity of find/insert/delete will be `log(n)` if you use binary search tree and expected complexity is constant if you use a hash table.

Comment: Hi, this is basically what I describe. The AVL / Hashmap to retrieve elements by id. Each element points to its next and previous just like a list

Comment: @Ervadac hmm the most important difference is that I suggest you to keep the two data structures separated. This will make things easier for you. Also a hash table may be a better option than an AVL tree.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider the [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) data structure.

It seems perfect for your case, because it has an expected `O(log(n))` insert / search / delete and if you have a pointer to a node, you can find the previous and the next element in `O(1)` by just moving that pointer.

The conclusion is that if you've just created a node, you have a pointer to it, and you can find the prev/next element in `O(1)` time.